# Image links in TVML templates created in Swift

Tags: javascript, tvos, tvml, tvjs

I am using local files to feed the templates for an Apple TV project. When I pass the Base URL of where my files reside, and then push the template, embedded image links work fine.

But when I create a template on the fly (as a string), and try to push that, the Base URL is not being read, and I get image links like this:

```
<heroImg src="${this.BASEURL}myImage.png"></heroImg>
```

Here is the javascript function that reads the string I create:

```
function myJSFunction (incomingString) {
    if (incomingString) {
        Presenter.showLoadingIndicator("defaultPresenter");
        var doc = Presenter.makeDocument(incomingString);
        Presenter.defaultPresenter.call(Presenter, doc);
    }
}
```

And the strings I am creating don't contain javascript, i.e. they don't start like this:

```
var Template = function() { return `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
etc
```

I know I could write the full Base URL into the image links, but is there any way of keeping the `${this.BASEURL}` in the paths I create?

Comment: Are you using TVMLKitTemplateCompilation as a starting point for your app?

Comment: @sailens, I am using Apple's `TVMLCatalogUsingTVMLTemplates` as my starting point.

Comment: Given I haven't heard any other possibilities, I am keeping an instance of my `baseURL` in a variable in swift, and using that to construct my paths, like: `<heroImg src="\(baseUrl)myImage.png"></heroImg>`

Comment: try using `resourceLoader.BASEURL`, as is the default in `TVMLCatalogUsingTVMLTemplates` for loading custom strings to the already loaded template